# How do I check a table is queryable?

Tags: mysql, database, slick

I wonder if there is a way using Slick to check that a particular database is connectable and queryable?

I have a table called 'User', for which I have an object model defined. 
I want to achieve my goal of queryability check without using my object model itself.

Comment: Can you describe what do you mean by an un-queryable table?

Comment: Simply put, the database is in good state and I can run queries on existing tables in the database. For example, "select * from table-name". I want to interact directly with my DB and not via may application (or I do not want to use my object model such as User)

Comment: What's a db in a "bad state" you cannot run queries against?

Comment: Database in a bad state can mean unexpected corrupted data, for example, unexpected column type change (from String to bigint while what we still want is 'String') or unexpected foreign key constraint removal, etc. The bad state I have just said might or might not make the DB unconnectable depending on the query, however I still want to detect the state of changes in those tables of DB.